# After hyperparameter tuning accuracy remains the same

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I was trying to hyper tune param but after I did it, the accuracy score has not changed at all, what I do wrong?

```
 # Log reg
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression(C=0.3326530612244898,max_iter=100,tol=0.01)
logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
​
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
​
print('Accuracy of log reg is: ', logreg.score(X_test,y_test))
​
confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
 # 0.9181286549707602 - acurracy before tunning
```

Output:

```
Accuracy of log reg is:  0.9181286549707602
array([[ 54,   9],
       [  5, 103]])
```

Here is me Using Grid Search CV:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
params ={'tol':[0.01,0.001,0.0001],
        'max_iter':[100,150,200],
        'C':np.linspace(1,20)/10}

grid_model = GridSearchCV(logreg,param_grid=params,cv=5)
grid_model_result = grid_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(grid_model_result.best_score_,grid_model_result.best_params_)
```

Output:

```
0.8867405063291139 {'C': 0.3326530612244898, 'max_iter': 100, 'tol': 0.01}
```

Comment: so the 1st time acc is: `0.9181286549707602` and 2nd time acc is: `0.8867405063291139` ?

Comment: During the GridSearchCV you perform 5-fold cross validation, meaning that 80% of X_train will be used to train your logistic regression algorithm while the first output is based on a model that is trained on 100% of X_train. Therefore, it could be that this 20% difference in data during training could lead to the difference in evaluation accuracy.

Comment: @meistef so there is always the possibility that GridSearchCV could result in lower accuracy? I though it is always supposed to make accuracy higher

Comment: @RuslanPylypiuk The principle of GridSearchCV is to find the optimal set of hyperparameters that would result in the highest accuracy for sure. But here you took the optimal set of parameters and then re-trained the model with these optimal parameters on more data (the full X_train set instead of the 80% X_train set). The first model had a chance to learn from more data together with the optimal hyperparameters. I am not suprised that there is a small difference in accuracy between the two instances.

Comment: @meistef how do I train on remaining 80% instead?

Comment: @RuslanPylypiuk I am not sure I understand what you mean? In the GridSearchCV you already perform a 5-fold cross valdation by setting te cv parameter to 5. This means that the input data (e.g. X_train and y_train) will be divided in five equal partitions of 20%, where four of these partitions will be used to train the model (e.g. 80% of the total X_train) and one partitions (e.g. 20% of the total X_train) to evaluate or validate the model with a specific set of hyperparameters that were optimized during training. I highly recommend looking up cross-validation on SciKit's website.

Comment: Now when I look at your code again, in GridSearchCV the refit parameter is True by default. Thus it should retrain on all the training data... Interesting. Can you maybe share your data so I can try it myself?

Comment: @meistef yeah, here it is [link](https://www.kaggle.com/merishnasuwal/breast-cancer-prediction-dataset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in the first chunk you evaluate the model's performance on the test set, while in the GridSearchCV you only looked at the performance on the training set after hyperparameter optimization.

The code below shows that both procedures, when used to predict the test set labels, **perform equally well in terms of accuracy (~0.93)**.

Note, you might want to consider using a hyperparameter grid with other solvers and a larger range of `max_iter` because I obtained convergence warnings.

```
# Load packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn import metrics

# Load the dataset and split in X and y
df = pd.read_csv('Breast_cancer_data.csv')
X = df.iloc[:, 0:5]
y = df.iloc[:, 5]

# Perform train and test split (80/20)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Initialize a model
Log = LogisticRegression(n_jobs=-1)

# Initialize a parameter grid
params = [{'tol':[0.01,0.001,0.0001],
        'max_iter':[100,150,200],
        'C':np.linspace(1,20)/10}]

# Perform GridSearchCV and store the best parameters
grid_model = GridSearchCV(Log,param_grid=params,cv=5)
grid_model_result = grid_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
best_param = grid_model_result.best_params_

# This step is only to prove that both procedures actually result in the same accuracy score
Log2 = LogisticRegression(C=best_param['C'], max_iter=best_param['max_iter'], tol=best_param['tol'], n_jobs=-1)
Log2.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Perform two predictions one straight from the GridSearch and the other one with manually inputting the best params
y_pred1 = grid_model_result.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)
y_pred2 = Log2.predict(X_test)

# Compare the accuracy scores and see that both are the same
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred1))
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred2))
```

Comment: so should i perform GridSearch on test if I used before that training ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say, but you perform GridSearchCV to find the combination of hyperparameters that result in the highest score during training. So, you perform GridSearchCV only on the train sets.

Comment: It still hard to get for me why they are same, as you saw in new question I fixed and completed right GridSearchCV but also resulted in no change

Comment: Maybe create a new question about GridSearchCV and try to explain more in-depth what you don't understand.